# How do I create a role using data browser?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

When I use the data browser in parse.com, I'm unable to create a "Role".
I have created the Role class, but when I go to create a row, as soon as I give the role a name, I get an error saying:
"Error: Roles must have an ACL specified."
Ok...fine...how do I create an ACL, then?
What am I missing?

Comment: If you scroll down a little bit from here: https://parse.com/docs/data#security-objects you'll find some sample ACLs.

Answer (score 3):

In Parse Server Dashboard 1.0.15 follow these steps to create a Role through the dashboard interface:

1. Navigate to the Role Class
2. Add a row
3. Click on 'name' and enter the name of the role you would like to add. At this point you will see the error 'ACL is required'
4. Click on 'ACL' and enter the name of the role you just tried to create in the 'Role or User...' form field
5. Save ACL

This should create a role that you can start working with